# The difference between the GRUCell function in pytorch and tensorflow

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to migrate my code from pytorch to tensorflow2.0, but I don't know how GRU and GRUCell in pytorch are implemented in tensorflow2.0.

```
self.dec_gru_a = nn.GRUCell(self.embed_size, self.hidden_size)
hidden = self.dec_gru_a(h, hidden)
```

Comment: So you read [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU) and your specific question is...? What was your attempt and how did it fail? Do you want to migrate code or trained models?

Comment: I migrated the code  from pytorch to tensorflow2.0, but when I trained my model, I got a different result, and I wasn't sure if it was correct to change GRUCell in pytorch to tensorflow like this     self.dec_gru_a =tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(self.hidden_size)
        self.rnn = tf.keras.layers.RNN(self.dec_gru_a,return_state=True)    hidden, state = self.rnn(h, hidden)

Comment: Please put the information into the question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58765610/edit). It will help others to help you :-)